# Is it possible to infer on the complexity of the input text of a sha256 hash?

Tags: r, complexity-theory, sha256

Consider the following example:

```
require(digest)

text_short <- "The short text."
text_long <- "The long text. This is a longer text for the purpose of testing."

text_short_hashed <- digest(text_short, algo="sha256")
[1] "6e504cb5660d8614be9465a3a9c0e0db9889d897cfd9e7432f98e5df566e9e95"
text_long_hashed <- digest(text_long, algo="sha256")
[1] "25face2d475dcb2b547f85a0109ae3a506385dcb72f639af1a354220d91a9426"
```

Is there any way to calculate or estimate the complexity of `text_short` and `text_long` based on their hashes: `text_short_hashed` and `text_long_hashed`? Complexity could be the **length**.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

No. The point of a secure hash is that you can't extract any information about the original text from the hash.

Comment: I would add that if only one bit is changed in a original string, at least half of hash bits must be changed.

Comment: Thanks. I am more interested in data mining than security. It would be great if there is some statistical analyses on the possible differences in statistics of the hashes of 10-character strings compared to those of 1000-chatacter string, for example.

Comment: You should read up on the sha256 algorithm - if you have the time and the interest, you might even think about watching Dan Boneh's lectures from his coursera course. That would hopefully convince you that if you were to find such an analysis you would have demonstrated that sha256 is broken and should not be used. This would be an interesting result, of course.